# How to use youtube-dl from a python program?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I would like to access the result of the following shell command,

```
youtube-dl -g "www.youtube.com/..."
```

to print its output `direct url` to a file, from within a python program. This is what I have tried:

```
import youtube-dl
fromurl="www.youtube.com/..."
geturl=youtube-dl.magiclyextracturlfromurl(fromurl)
```

Is that possible?
I tried to understand the mechanism in the source but got lost: `youtube_dl/__init__.py`, `youtube_dl/youtube_DL.py`, `info_extractors` ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Comment: @lollercoaster, that URL is dead... [Fixed link here](https://willdrevo.com/downloading-youtube-and-soundcloud-audio-with-python-and-pandas).

Answer (score 203, accepted):

It's not difficult and [actually documented](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl):

```
import youtube_dl

ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({'outtmpl': '%(id)s.%(ext)s'})

with ydl:
    result = ydl.extract_info(
        'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc',
        download=False # We just want to extract the info
    )

if 'entries' in result:
    # Can be a playlist or a list of videos
    video = result['entries'][0]
else:
    # Just a video
    video = result

print(video)
video_url = video['url']
print(video_url)
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: import youtube_dl
ImportError: No module named youtube_dl

Comment: You have to install the youtube_dl : if you have the pip utility (to install it, sudo apt-get install python-pip ) you can to sudo pip install youtube-dl

Comment: If you have "No module named youtube_dl" on gentoo you can try to add "#!/usr/bin/env python2.7" to the start of python file.

Comment: is there a way to pass a variable to the options object? 
Something like: 'outtmpl' : '%(my_variable)s%(id)s.%(ext)s'

Comment: The variables supported for `outtmpl` are listed [in the README](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/23905927e19280d9217ecad377ef26ea9d5793fe/README.md#output-template)

Comment: I know this is old and there are other answers but just to clarify. On new versions of youtube_dl  there were some changes and instead of `video['url']` it changed to `video['webpage_url']`

Comment: How can we add "-c" or continue flag in the options?

Comment: The script you gave if wrong if the video url contains "entries". it should be something like try :video = result['entries'][0] except: video=result

Comment: `video['url`]` or `video[webpage_url]` just repeats the same url. I haven't found a way to get the actual stream urls (for both audio or video)

Comment: What is the purpose of `with ydl:`?

Comment: `ydl` is an object of the type `youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts)`

Answer (score 12):

For simple code,
may be i think

```
import os
os.system('youtube-dl [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]')
```

Above is just running command line inside python.

Other is mentioned in the documentation [Using youtube-dl on python](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl)
Here is the way

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc'])
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way.

We set-up options' string, in a list, just as we set-up command line arguments. In this case `opts=['-g', 'videoID']`. Then, invoke `youtube_dl.main(opts)`. In this way, we write our custom .py module, `import youtube_dl` and then invoke the `main()` function.

Comment: this kind of works, nothing is returned from the main function, so you can't really get the value of it yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals 
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {} 
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['Your youtube url'])
```

You can use 'format', 'continue', 'outtmpl' in ydl_opts
As example;

```
ydl_opts= {
           'format': '22',
           'continue': True,
           'outtmpl': '%(uploader)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s',
           'progress_hooks': [my_hook],
          }

def my_hook(d):
    if d['status'] == 'downloading':
        print('Downloading video!')
    if d['status'] == 'finished':
        print('Downloaded!')
```

When you need to stop playlist downloading, Just add this code into ydl_opts.

```
'noplaylist': True;
```

Answer (score -3):

Usage: `python3 AudioFromYtVideo.py link outputName`

```py
import os
from sys import argv

try:
    if argv[1] and argv[2]:
        pass
except:
    print("Input: python3 [programName] [url] [outputName]")    

os.system('youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 -o '+argv[2]+' '+argv[1])
```

Answer (score -8):

If `youtube-dl` is a terminal program, you can use the `subprocess` module to access the data you want.

Check out this link for more details: [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: That's a bit sad to call a python program from a python program, isn't it ?

Comment: I consider `youtube-dl` to be a command-line program written in Python and see nothing wrong with calling it from the command-line. If you want to muck around with the source code, please feel free to do so.

Comment: @Xaranke You have a lot more control if you import youtube-dl as a module from python. Parsing printed data from command line is nowhere as reliable.

Comment: Also, I dare you to actually try using subprocess/os.system on this youtube-dl command. It doesn't actually work very well, nor as intended, when trying to pass arguments.

Answer (score -11):

I would like this

```
from subprocess import call

command = "youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NG3WygJmiVs -c"
call(command.split(), shell=False)
```