# how to use a key words instead of a url with youtube-dl and discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, youtube-dl

i am writing an all purpose bot basicly i want to to type the command and then a song name example:`?play song-name` and it will search youtube and the first video that pops up it will download the audio of it

I got the bot to work with normal links but if i have to get the link to play the music it defeats the purpose

```
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    ydl_opts = {
            'format': 'beataudio/best',
            'postprocessors': [{
                'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                'preferredquality': '192'
            }]
        }
     with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
          print("Downloading audio now\n")
          url: str = message.content.replace('?play ', '')
          print(url)
          ydl.download([url])
```

i did not use youtube-dl before so I donot know how it works.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/643286/can-i-download-videos-from-a-youtube-search-query-using-youtube-dl

Comment: did not find what i was looking for. @ZacharyCraig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get the discord search query, you can use:

```
import youtube_dl  # youtube-dl-2020.3.1
import traceback, os, json
from youtube_search import YoutubeSearch  # pip install youtube_search 
"""
sources :
https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23727943/how-to-get-information-from-youtube-dl-in-python/31184514#31184514
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43143553/797495
"""

search = 'carlos paiao playback'
ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'beataudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192'
    }]
}
yt = YoutubeSearch(search, max_results=1).to_json()
try:
    yt_id = str(json.loads(yt)['videos'][0]['id'])
    yt_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+yt_id
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([yt_url])
        info = ydl.extract_info(yt_url)
        songname = info.get('title', None) + "-" + yt_id + ".mp3"
        if os.path.isfile(songname):
            print("Song Downloaded: " + songname)
        else:
            print("Error: " + songname)
except:
    pass
    print(traceback.print_exc())
    print("no results")
```