# Get the YouTube video title by its url using python

Tags: python, url, search, youtube, extract

I want to get the title of a youtube video by url. I have been searching for several days but I did not get the result

I have been searching for several days but I did not get the result

Comment: This doesn't seem possible unless you extract the video's id from the URL and make a call to the API

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23727943/how-to-get-information-from-youtube-dl-in-python

Answer (score 4):

By using requests and Beautiful Soup libraries you can achieve that:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sg-A-eS6Ig&list=RDBAkqJT_sMKQ&index=5")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

link = soup.find_all(name="title")[0]
title = str(link)
title = title.replace("<title>","")
title = title.replace("</title>","")

print(title)
```

Comment: `title = link.text` is a much cleaner way to get the title

Comment: ``soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features="lxml")``