# Access local variable of function while running in another thread -youtube-dl- example

Tags: python, multithreading, function

## I want to :

> 1/Fetch youtube-channel or playlist
>
> 2/take the url of videos.
>
> 3/process them : view them to the user, or start downloading by anotrher download manager.

### Function to get information from youtube-dl :

thanks to [jaimeMF answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054500/how-to-use-youtube-dl-from-a-python-program)

```
import time 
import youtube_dl
def myfunc(url):
    ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL()
    # Add all the available extractors
    ydl.add_default_info_extractors()
    result = ydl.extract_info( url , download=False)

    ##  ydl.extract_info() collect `url fetched info` in local variable called "ie_result"; It return this "ie_result" when finshed.
    if 'entries' in result:       # Can be a playlist or a list of videos
                      video = result['entries'][0]
    else:
        # Just a video
        video = result      # get desired data
      res.append(desired data)
      return res
```

### Problem:

If the `url` is `youtube:channel` or `youtube:playlist`; youtube-dl will fetch urls one by one; consuming long time to return information; `you can imagine the time of fetching cannel contaiing 500 videos information`.

So I want to get the `res` list simultaneously; to start viewing them to the user or start downloading them by another downloader. etc.

### Trial:

I think in the following design :

```
def get_res():
     args    = ['http://www.youtube.com/channel/url']
     thread1 = threading.Thread(target=myfun , args )
     thread1.run()     
     #  access myfun.res.ie_result by anyway  #.... this is the problem
     # return its value     

def worker():
     processed_res = []
     while True:
         res = get_res()
         for item in res :
             if item not in processed_res:
                  # do something like; 
                  # start viewing it to the user, 
                  # or start downloading them by another downloader.
                  processed_res.append(item) 
         time.sleep(1)             
         # break when tread1 terminate 

get_res()
worker()
```

### The code defect:

The actual problem remain in ***access myfun.res.ie_result by anyway *** in the function `get_res`;

### in brief:

Is it possible to access the local variable of running function from other thread ?
Any help is appreciated :D 
Any trial to solve the problem by another way is also.

---

*** Items to be remembered :***

> I have edited the code to bit clarify it.
>
> the `myfun` call the `extract_info()` function. in its `result` local variable.
>
> the `extract_info()` function collect results in variable called `ie_result`
>
> `extract_info` fetch the url data one by one the return all in a list.
>   collecting it.
>
> The `myfun.res.ie_result` is equal to `ydl.extract_info(url).ie_result`

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to accomplish anyway.  Do you want to obtain a partial `res` while it is still being collected by the other function?  Why?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what you want to do, rather than telling us what code you think will do it? We are trying to guess what you mean from your code, but I don't think your code is what you mean.

Comment: (Normally it's good to include your code, but in this case you haven't included enough extra information.)

Comment: Note that you should call the [`start()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start) method of a `Thread` if you want to get any parallelism. Calling `run()` will just result in a normal function call.

Comment: Thanks for your time,  `Do you want to obtain a partial res while it is still being collected by the other function?` the answer is `Yes`.`WHY?` the answer is `To save user time`

Comment: the code have been edited many times??; Is it clear now ??

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a bit vague and code in context is required to answer it. But I think classes should be the solution
You need to create a class and list your function definitions in it. You should then add the prefix 'self.' to any local variable you want to access globally.

For how to create a class:
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: That doesn't help if the requirement is to leave `myfun()` untouched.

Comment: Please refer to the question again; I have edit it many times to specify the problem.