# installing youtube-dl for import youtube_dl in my code

Tags: python, discord.py, youtube-dl

I would like to import youtube-dl into my code for a discord.py bot
I have not understood how to install the youtube-dl package on my pc. (I downloaded the .exe file etc, but I don't understand).

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: If you install it via `pip install --upgrade youtube-dl` is it useable as a library? The .exe is just the standalone compiled version of the program, you can't just use it as a library.

Answer (score 1):

Installing packages for Python goes via `pip` most of the time, execute this command in your terminal:

```
pip install youtube_dl
```

For more info about importing into your python application please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054500/how-to-use-youtube-dl-from-a-python-program)

Comment: thank you for answering me

Comment: Hey @Théo , if you thought my answer was helpful please consider marking it as accepted. If you dont know how, you can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)!

Answer (score -1):

You need to execute `pip install youtube-dl` in your terminal

After that, you can import the module with `from youtube-dl import *`

Comment: When I execute `pip install youtube-dl`, it shows me this in the terminal: 

Requirement already satisfied: youtube-dl in c:\users\ready player\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (2021.6.6)

I guess that's ok. But when I write: `from youtube-dl import *` it tells me that it does not recognize this import.
Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Execute `pip uninstall youtube-dl` to uninstall the module and reinstall it after that