# Taking a section of subprocess output on each line using regex and sending it real-time

Tags: python, subprocess, polling, youtube-dl

I wrote this function to take the `subprocess` output line-by-line, which then `yield`s each line and sends it to the user.

```py
def invoke_process_popen_poll_live(command, shellType=False, stdoutType=subprocess.PIPE):
    """runs subprocess with Popen/poll so that live stdout is shown"""
    try:
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=shellType, stdout=stdoutType, universal_newlines=True)
    except:
        print("ERROR {} while running {}".format(sys.exc_info()[1], command))
        return None
    while True:
        output = process.stdout.readline()
        yield output.strip()
        if process.poll() is not None:
            break
        if output:
            output.strip()
    rc = process.poll()
    return rc
```

The output is the `youtube-dl` download stats which is like this:

```
[youtube] knge_1uWbro: Downloading webpage
[download] Destination: ./DLVids/Kitty_says_Uh-Oh_very_clearly-knge_1uWbro-720.f398.mp4

[download]   0.1% of 963.52KiB at  3.82KiB/s ETA 04:11
[download]   0.3% of 963.52KiB at 11.46KiB/s ETA 01:23
[download]   0.7% of 963.52KiB at 26.61KiB/s ETA 00:35\n
.
.
.
```

Is there any way to take each line's output like this:

```
0.1% of 963.52KiB at  3.82KiB/s
0.3% of 963.52KiB at 11.46KiB/s
0.7% of 963.52KiB at 26.61KiB/s
```

Comment: while this question still seems interesting, specifically for youtube-dl, it's written in Python and can be imported and controlled directly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054500/how-to-use-youtube-dl-from-a-python-program

Comment: @ti7 thanks, I'm aware of it but I've written my whole app in the hard way (though for me, importing was hard too! there was a little doc)  just don't know how to send the download stat to the user.